# SQL Server : return only max from count per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The following query returns: multiple dates (with count for each user per day), IP count, username.

I need it to return only max values for user (only the highest one) per day.

If I remove the username from the group by, it works just fine. The problem is that I also need the username in the table results.

I tried using a sub query with no lock.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FORMAT([UTCTimestamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS 'DATE',
    T.Username,
    COUNT(clientIP) AS "CountClientIP" 
FROM
    dbo.tablename O
LEFT JOIN
    [DBNAME2]..vwAD_tablename T ON T.UserID = O.userID
LEFT JOIN
    [DBNAME1]..Event E ON E.Code = O.Code  
WHERE 
    FORMAT([UTCTimestamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE '2018-01-%' 
    AND T.Username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY   
    T.Username, FORMAT([UTCTimestamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY 
    FORMAT([UTCTimestamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd'), COUNT(clientIP) DESC
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Questions like these get answered much better and faster if you include some sample data and expected results. Please add them to your question, but not as an image but as text we can copy/paste.

Comment: Side point: `CAST(... AS date)` is much better for truncating time component from a `datetime`. Your `left join`s don't make sense because you have `where` on them, perhaps those conditions should be in the `on` or perhaps it should be `inner join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ROW_NUMBER, wrap it in a sub-query, then filter on it.

```
SELECT [DATE], Username, CountClientIP
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        FORMAT([UTCTimestamp],'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [DATE],
        T.Username,
        COUNT(DISTINCT clientIP) AS [CountClientIP], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FORMAT([UTCTimestamp],'yyyy-MM-dd')
                           ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT clientIP) DESC) AS rn
    FROM [DBNAME].dbo.tablename O
    LEFT JOIN [DBNAME2]..[vwAD_tablename] T ON T.UserID = O.userID
    LEFT JOIN [DBNAME1]..[Event] E ON E.Code = O.Code  
    WHERE FORMAT([UTCTimestamp],'yyyy-MM-dd') LIKE '2018-01-%' 
      AND T.Username IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY T.Username, FORMAT([UTCTimestamp],'yyyy-MM-dd')
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Comment: Solved my problem ! Cant thank you enough :)

Comment: Thanks. Btw, this method works simply because the [window functions](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/) are processed after the aggregation.

Comment: On a side-note, use DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER if you want to report more than one user that has the top 1 CountClientIP